# Can WebSphere Liberty servers use their own extension folder?

Tags: websphere-liberty, server-configuration

I have the following WebSphere Liberty file layout (with a few choice directories and files show) which uses a custom usr dir of wlp-usr.

```
wlp/etc/server.env
wlp-usr/servers/server1/apps/
wlp-usr/servers/server1/extension/
wlp-usr/servers/server1/resource/
wlp-usr/servers/server1/bootstrap.properties
wlp-usr/servers/server1/jvm.options
wlp-usr/servers/server1/server.xml
wlp-usr/servers/server2/apps/
wlp-usr/servers/server2/extension/
wlp-usr/servers/server2/resource/
wlp-usr/servers/server2/bootstrap.properties
wlp-usr/servers/server2/jvm.options
wlp-usr/servers/server2/server.xml
```

The file wlp8554/etc/server.env contains

`WLP_USER_DIR=/home/me/wlp-usr`

I want to get the servers (there will be more than 2) using their own extension folders, rather than the default `wlp-usr/extension/lib`.

The documentation on Liberty directory locations and properties suggests that `usr.extension.dir` is what I want. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_dirs.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-2-3

I have tried setting this in `bootstrap.properties` and `jvm.options`, but without success. I am wondering if this is a read only property or if it is something that I can actually set. Has anyone used separate extension directories before? Is this even possible? If so then some guidance on how would be most appreciated.

Cheers, Steve

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  The extension folder is for Product Extension, which store user developed features.  Is this what you are trying to do?  If so, here is the complete document.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_prod_ext.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usr/extension` directory is per-user-directory, so it is effectively read-only from a server perspective (all the variables on that page are derived and cannot be changed except `wlp.user.dir`, which can be set by `WLP_USER_DIR`, and `server.output.dir`, which is derived from `WLP_OUTPUT_DIR`).  That is, it is not possible to have per-server extensions.  If you really need that capability for some reason, then I would recommend opening an RFE.

That said, `usr/extension` is really intended for convenience during feature development (or perhaps for minor deployment scenarios).  [Product extensions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_prod_ext.html) are really intended to be applied to an entire installation, so they should probably be used for any sophisticated environments.  Since individual servers are unaffected by extension features unless they enable them, there should not be much reason to have per-server extensions anyway.

Comment: It is worth adding that none of the variables listed in the linked document can be set in server configuration. They are read only and derived from other content.

Comment: @Alasdair None except a few; updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments @Alasdair and @bkail . I had seen `server.output.dir` being set in server configuration before, but I wasn't sure which of the properties could be set there. It seems very few, as I expected.

The reason for using separate extension dirs would have been to provide the ability to supply hot fixes to our extensions to only a limited number of servers for stability, before ultimately rolling them out to all servers. We can switch to multiple Liberty runtime installations, which might be good for upgrade paths long term anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: @Stephen Yes, I think separate wlp installs is your best option.  You should be able to group all your server configurations in the same WLP_USER_DIR, but launch a subset of them using the newer runtime.  It's a little unfortunate that you're required to have full copies of the wlp runtime just to have separate copies of your extension, but there's no other option at present.